# willTransitionToTraitCollection not get called, why?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios8

I am trying to replace `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` with `willTransitionToTraitCollection` - in a UIViewController subclass - as doc says, but method is not get called when I am rotating device. Why?

Comment: Same case here for iPhone! I have explicitly resized the screen size using the resizable iPhone, even then none of the (willTransitionToTraitCollection or viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:) are being called.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're testing this on iPad it has regular trait collections for vertical and horizontal class for both orientations, thus it will not call this method when orientation changed.

Comment: I am testing on iPad, that is right, but then what else procedure do you recommend to get notification about view controller rotation occured?

Comment: You can use finer-grain [viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIContentContainer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIContentContainer/viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:)

Comment: In my case, I'm testing a modal view controller on an iPad. I don't get the viewWillTransitionToSize notification on the iPad either. I do get it when it's presented on an iPhone.

Comment: willTransitionToTraitCollection is still not called when the trait collection is changed in the resizable simulator.