# Transition not occurring properly in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uideviceorientation

The function  override

```
func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) { }
```

is not triggered when I build and run on iPad devices but it works fine in mobile devices(iphone 5,6,7...). How to solve this??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [willTransitionToTraitCollection not get called, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25634085/willtransitiontotraitcollection-not-get-called-why)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function is not called because iPad has Regular traits for any rotation. Prefer using [func viewWillTransition(to: CGSize, with: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition) instead.